# Unable to install libapache2-mod-spamhaus E: Unable to locate package "libapache2-mod-spamhaus" in Ubuntu 18 Apache 2.4.29

Tags: software-installation, apache-httpd

Somehow, I'm not able to install Spamhaus module using `apt-get` and I didn't find any tarball to install it manually. It was working smoothly in Ubuntu 16.04.
Is `mod_spamhaus` not supporting Ubuntu 18 and Apache 2.4.9?
Kindly provide a suggestion how to install this plugin.

```
root@ip~#  apt-get update -y

Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:3 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease [6349 B]                                  
Get:4 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                  
Get:5 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Get:6 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [1752 kB]
Get:7 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1691 kB]
Fetched 3702 kB in 2s (1724 kB/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done

root@ip~# apt install libapache2-mod-spamhaus

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-spamhaus

root@ip~#
```

Answer (score 0):

`libapache2-mod-spamhaus`, which is the Apache DNSBL module that blocks listed IP addresses, [is available only in Ubuntu Xenial (16.04 LTS)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/web/libapache2-mod-spamhaus). This is why `apt` is not able to find and install the package in Ubuntu Bionic (18.04 LTS). It is not present in the repository.

You can still download the package or the source at [the package's page on the Ubuntu's website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/web/libapache2-mod-spamhaus) and attempt installing either of them, e.g.:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ./libapache2-mod-spamhaus_0.7-1.1_amd64.deb
```

According to the change log, the package was ported to Apache 2.4, but, considering that it didn't make it to Bionic, you might have trouble installing or running it. Be careful.

The original code and a few forks are also [available on GiHub](https://github.com/search?q=mod_spamhaus). [The one from kaufmannr](https://github.com/kaufmannr/mod_spamhaus_new) seems to be the most maintained as it had some updates this year.

You may also want to look at the [discussion of this module at Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/30230/241015).